# How to solve $\log \sqrt[3]{x} = \sqrt{\log x} ?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

How to solve $$\log \sqrt[3]{x} = \sqrt{\log x} $$

Comment: I've edited your post to include MathJax; please verify that it's correct.

Comment: its right, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using $$m\log a=\log(a^m)$$ when both logs are defined

$$\log\sqrt[3] x=\sqrt{\log x}\implies\frac13 \log x=\sqrt{\log x}$$

$$\sqrt{\log x}(\sqrt{\log x}-3)=0$$

$$\sqrt{\log x}=0\iff \log x=0\iff x=1$$

$$\sqrt{\log x}-3=0\iff \log x=9$$

Comment: i dont understand the second line. can you explain it please.

Comment: @user3175999, have you understood the first line?

Comment: yes, but isnt the 3 suppposed to be 1/3

Comment: @user3175999, $$\frac13 \log x=\sqrt{\log x}\iff \log x=3\sqrt{\log x}$$  right?

Comment: i see , thanks.

Comment: @user3175999 $$\log\sqrt[3]{x}=\log x^{1/3}=\dfrac13\log x$$